# CSS Help for IE 7/8

Tags: css

I develop on Mac.  I'm having trouble with my #slider div in IE 7/8.

Can you help me with the CSS?  The #slider div (from what I can see on browsershots.org) fans out, rather than hiding the overflow.

(Old link removed)

Comment: If this is a bad question then people will downvote it. Don't tell people what to do just so you can save a couple of rep points. (BTW this is a perfectly valid question, but if you think it's a bad question, why are you asking it?)

Comment: The link above is broken, and the question relies on it exclusively, so unfortunately this question will have to be put on hold. Please always write questions without external links as much as possible - put everything the user needs to know in the actual question.

Comment: @halfer you're right. This question should be closed or deleted.

Comment: Great, I've voted to close. I think it needs to be closed before it can be deleted. Perhaps other people will see it in the close queue, and will add their votes.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known IE7 bug that kept be busy quite some time a while back.

This starts happening when you introduce `position: relative` to one of the elements inside of the container.  This is fixed by adding `position: relative;` to the container itself, in your case

```
#slider {
  ..
  position: relative;
  ..
}
```

I started developing on a mac as well a year ago, It's a real pain when confronted with IE bugs. It helps if you setup a Remote Desktop Connection to a test PC if you have one and install [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) on it (mind though that IE Tester is not 100% the same thing so you should always do a final check on the real thing).

On a side note, Adobe has a really sexy browser screenshot test app at http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/browserlab/

Comment: Be careful with this, though, if you're only relying on browsershots.org. When I add `position: relative`, the arrows in the slider are positioned wrongly, and the border around it remains stuck to the first image, scrolling along with it. You don't see that in a screenshot.

Comment: Ahhh. Any idea how to fix the border?
(I fixed the arrows, that was easy)
IE is a MAJOR pain...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

It looks fine for me on IE8

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't rely on browsershots.org for testing. Most of their screenshot factories are broken, I always get pages either half-loaded or not loaded at all. And it doesn't verify that the slider works at all.

Comment: Can you check the nav?  There should be a jQuery drop-down for each item.

Comment: Thanks, Blake! You've been a help!